# Was Adam created by Allah by his hands?

Tags: quran, hadith-interpretation, divine-attributes

There are several ahadith which mention 4 things were created by Allah by his hands which also include Adam and for the rest He only said "Be". Are these authentic? If so then how can we reconcile it with quran 3:59 which specifically mentions that Adam was too created through "Be"?

Comment: Allah creating Adam by His Hands is corroborated by the Quran: [38:75](https://quran.com/38/75?translations=20). This does not preclude Allah also saying 'Be', rather both are true. Reread 3:59 carefully: "He created Him from dust; then He said to him, "Be," and he was."

Answer (score -1):

The message that He made Adam with his hands and that Satan was created from fire, implying that he didn't make him by his hands is already contained in the Qur'an (78:75-76)

> He said, “O Satan, what prevented you from prostrating before what I created with My Own hands? Are you too proud, or were you one of the exalted?
> He said, “I am better than he; You created me from fire, and You created him from clay.” (76) He said, “Then get out of here! You are an outcast!

And also that He said: Be! (2:117)

> The Originator is He of the heavens and the earth: and when He wills a thing to be, He but says unto it, 'Be' -and it is. (asad)

Nevertheless, God is not a human; saying " with My own Hand" is an image made for us because creation is beyond our capacity of imagination.

To have a hint on the authenticity ratings of a particular hadith, you should cite it.

Comment: "When any one of you fights with his brother, he should avoid his face for Allah created Adam in His own image." - Prophet Muhammad PBUH